# Updating HTML in element not 'invalidating' or refreshing on the page

Tags: javascript, html

I am testing the navigator.geolocation.watchPosition method and within the callback method for watchPosition I update a p element's html with some data.

In testing with various browsers (Chrome, FireFox, Safari, Phonegap->iOS) the behavior seems to be that the watchPosition function is called once and the html is correctly updated, BUT it is never called again unless I do something like switch to another tab and back, minimize the browser and bring it back up, etc. What is causing this?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y9WP2/

```
geoLoc.watchPosition(showPosition,
                      errorHandler,
                      options);
```

Comment: Note: I understand that watchPosition is supposed to update on the event of position change, but I have tested the rungoals site and a phonegap'd version on my iPhone and see similar / sporadic behavior.

Comment: Also: I have set the timeout to 10000 in my current version. Doesn't that mean watchPosition should fire every 10s no matter what??

Comment: Please isolate the issue to post code here or make a fiddle.

Comment: Added jsfiddle to op. Note how the update count only updates after tabbing (refreshing the window).. and does not seem to use the timeout option. I am leaning towards using my own setTimeout and just using geolocation.getCurrentPosition because that actually works..